# re] how to use multi-bluetooth from Android studio?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want making multi-bluetooth from Android studio.

I found multi-bluetooth java code libraries.

but I am difficult to use. (Because I do not speak English well :'-()

[find site 1](https://arissa34.github.io/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/)

[find site 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/adeBD275u30)

I want to make. (from Android studio)

[Fitness game machine 1 & joystick 1 - Bluetooth Android phone 1]

It is possible to implement?

Please tell me on a site presented above, helpful site that correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible to connect with multi-bluetooth devices.
For the joystick, you may connect it with HID, and , you really need to nothing at Android side; the system Bluetooth apps would help you to do that.

Regarding to the game machine, why don't you put it as the single devices :-)

Comment: Big Thank you ~! Your advice was helpful.

Comment: My pleasure. enjoy it :-)